# How to get all the words "bar" after the word "foo" with regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to retrieve all occurrences of the **word** bar after the word **foo**.

Below the content:

> fuu
>
> *bar*
>
> faa
>
> foo**bar** fuu
>
> **bar** fuu**bar**
>
> **bar**
>
> **bar** fuu

I want to retrieve all bars that are bold and disregard the first bar that is in italic format.

I tried to use the follow regular expression:

```
(?<=foo)bar
```

But that only catches the first occurrence.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the support guys. 
Below the data more closer to reality:

```
Some data

name: Person 1

Some data

my_delimiter:

 name: Person 2

 Some data

name: Person 3

Some data

 name: Person 4

 Some data

Some data
```

I want to get the name of the persons after **my_delimiter:**

I am testing here https://regex101.com/r/HrCLva/2

Comment: Are you replacing those matches or just extract?

Comment: Split one time by foo and the simply search by bar.

Comment: just curious, how is the second from last bar different from the 2nd one? Other than being bold

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just need to extract

Comment: You need the words or just "bar"?

Comment: you could extract any of the bars you want because it seems the have a space after, with (?:bar )

Comment: Ok, so, you can't use an infinite width lookbehind like `(?<=foo.*?)` in Python `re` thus just get a substring after the first `foo`, and extract from this part. In a very quick & dirty way: `re.findall(r'bar', text.split('foo', 2)[1])`

Comment: @JulianoPacheco: You can do this using `regex` module in python instead of `re`

Comment: Also, you may install the PyPi regex module and use `regex.findall(r'(?s)(?<=foo.*?)bar', text)`, see https://rextester.com/ZSII13536

Comment: Using the `PyPi regex` module as suggested by @WiktorStribiżew, you could also use `(?:foo|\G(?!\A)).*?\Kbar`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I had already thought of trying this way (using substring), but in my case (which is not in question) I also get the text that comes next to the word "bar", so I use need to use regex and in python I put it in a findall function.

Comment: @JulianoPacheco it can't be accomplished with the `re` module in python alone. You have to either substring it, or use the `regex` module.

Comment: See https://rextester.com/ZSII13536 with the PyPi regex (install with `pip install regex` to use it)

Comment: @oppressionslayer It is a fictitious example, in our case the word may be joined by another.

Comment: @JulianoPacheco is the actual answer to oppressionslayer's question about the 2nd vs. 2nd to last bar the following: on the 4th line we encounter 'foo', so everything past that 'foo' and any line afterwards (whether or not those remaining lines have 'foo') can be searched for 'bar'.

Comment: Follow regex101 example, in my case I need only "bar" after the "foo" word https://regex101.com/r/nMJQYM/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Perhaps this is off-topic but: on `regtester.com` how did you install `regex`? TIA

Comment: @RonaldAaronson Yeah, it's off-topic, but they installed the `regex` module there themselves.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But seemingly *not* under Python **3**. Thanks.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson That is why I shared the link to Python 2 demo. It is just a demo.

Comment: @JulianoPacheco Please update the question with real life data. It will make the question more answerable than it is now.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/HrCLva/3, use with PyPi regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you updated your answer, you don't need a regex lookbehind, you can use a regex like this to find the first name after your delimiter:

```
my_delimiter:\s+name:\s*(.*)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/HrCLva/4)**

On the other hand, if you want all names after your delimiter, then you can use a regex trick like this and then grab the content from capturing group:

```
[\s\S]*my_delimiter|name:\s*(.*)$
```

**[Working demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/HrCLva/5)**

The capturing group stores the data highlighted in green.

[image]

Comment: This solution worked, but due to the "|" operator, the time cost became too high, leading to some timeouts when applied to large text.

Comment: @JulianoPacheco, yes... this regex is expensive but your use case is a "complex" scenario as well for regex. You can try using this alternative `[\s\S]*my_delimiter|name:\s*([^\n]+)$` and check if it improves the performance

Answer (score 1):

Two things, depending on what exactly you're after:

1. If you're after all the occurrences on a single line, then you need to use `re.findall`:

   ```
   exp = re.compile("foo(?:.*?((bar)+)*)") # See https://regex101.com/r/zzBFFb/1
   match = exp.findall(mystring)
   ```
2. If you're after all occurrences on multiple lines as above then you need to add some flags to tell it not to treat newlines differently:

   ```
   exp = re.compile("foo(?:.*?((bar)+)*)", re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE) 
   match = exp.findall(mystring)
   ```